# Beautiful Soup not working in for loop more than once

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run a for loop to get further information out of a result set but it breaks after the first run.

```
classid = ["ccid_10132191", "ccid_10132192", 'ccid_9829339', 'ccid_9829337']

with open('output.html') as fp:
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
for classes in classid:
  grade = str(soup.find_all(id = '' + classes))
  soup = BeautifulSoup(grade, 'html.parser')
  print(soup.find(class_='bold').contents)
```

When I run this I get the desired outcome once then `grade = str(soup.find_all(id = '' + classes))` stops working and returns "[]"

```
str(soup.find_all(id = '' + classes) find blocks of HTML all similar to
```

```html
<tr class="center" id="ccid_10132191">
<td>1(A)</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left">CERAMICS BEGINNING&nbsp;<br><a href="teacherinfo.html?frn=0019424&nolink=true" title="Details about" class="button mini dialogM"><em class="ui-icon ui-icon-white ui-icon-contact"></em></a>&nbsp;<a href="mailto:">Email</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;Rm: 156</td>
<td class="colorMyGrade"><a href="scores.html?frn=004615841&begdate=09/01/2024&enddate=11/14/2026&fg=Q1&schoolid=" class="bold">A<br>100</a></td>
<td class="colorMyGrade"><a href="scores.html?frn=0046041&fg=Q2&schoolid=">[ i ]</a></td>
<td class="colorMyGrade"><a href="scores.html?frn=004615041&begdate=09/01/2021&enddate=01/26/2022&fg=S1&schoolid=" class="bold">A<br>100</a></td>
<td class="notInSession">&nbsp;<span class="screen_readers_only">Not available</span></td><td class="notInSession">&nbsp;<span class="screen_readers_only">Not available</span></td><td class="notInSession">&nbsp;<span class="screen_readers_only">Not available</span></td><td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
```

The only difference is the id and text content

Comment: Do include the URL that you are trying to scrape.

Comment: It is a password-protected website I'm using selenium-wire to get a login and then copy a request body. I can provide the HTML it is refrencing.

Comment: I think this is happening because your code changes the meaning of `soup` inside the loop.

Comment: @BoarGules you were right just wrote a solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @BoarGules said this happens because soup is redefined inside the for loop

A solution to this is the following code

```
classid = ["ccid_10132191", "ccid_10132192", 'ccid_9829339', 'ccid_9829337']
classhtml = []

with open('output.html') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
    for classes in classid:
      grade = str(soup.find_all(id = '' + classes))
      classhtml.append(grade) 

for classs in classhtml:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(classs, 'html.parser')
  print(soup.find(class_='bold').contents)
```